# Space shooter - shoot function

Tags: javascript, html

I have some problem with this code to work. I want to create the effect of shooter game but when I create a div I have to wait until it finishes its animation before create another one, how could I made it? Please help.

```
function createShot (){
 div[i] = document.createElement("div");
 screen.appendChild(div[i]);
div[i].style.height = 5 + "px";
div[i].style.position = "absolute";
div[i].style.border = 2 + "px solid #F30";
div[i].style.width = 5 + "px";
div[i].style.left = x+3 + "px";
div[i].style.top = divy + "px";
t = setInterval (shot,1);
}
function shot (){
    if (divy <= 0){
        screen.removeChild(div[i]);
          divy = 260;
          clearInterval (t);
    } else {
          divy -= 5;
         div[i].style.top = divy + "px";
    }
}
tshoot = setInterval(createShot,1000);
```

Comment: For one, I'm really not sure what you're asking; but it's probably something to do with the fact that you're re-using the same variable `t` for all the `setInterval()` calls. Either way, this is just really not a good approach to code a game in JS. You should use `<canvas>` for graphics and `requestAnimationFrame()` for updating. You can read up here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games

Comment: @MátéSafranka thank you. I'll watch this link

Answer (score 0):

Looks like i is global and not incremented, so you cannot have more than one shoot instance at a time. Relying on globals is a bad practice, especially in an asynchronous environment. Here is a working example:

```
var shoot = function(div)
{ 
    var x = parseInt(div.style.left); 
    x++;
    if (x>1000) {
        clearInterval(div.t); 
        document.body.removeChild(div);
        return;
    } 
    div.style.left = x+'px'; 
}    
var createShot = function(){ 
    var div = document.createElement('div');div.style.height = 5 + "px";
    div.style.position = "fixed";
    div.style.border = "5px solid red";
    div.style.width = "5px";
    div.style.left = "0px";
    div.style.top = "100px";
    document.body.appendChild(div); 
    div.t = setInterval(shoot, 10, div);
}
setInterval(createShot, 200)
```